# Trouble with targetting elements for the JQuery fade-in on window scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply the effect where elements fade-in as the page is scrolled down to a level where they'd be visible.

To be specific, I'm trying to target the boxes in a vertical timeline.

This is the structure of the timeline.

```
<div class="container-fluid when">

    <div class="container none">
        <div class="title dark">When?</div>
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="container none">

              <!-- BOX START -->
                <div class="entry fade">
                    <div class="container-fluid none date-title">
                        <div class="col-md-6 none">The Pledge</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 none">November 23rd 2011</div>
                    </div>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum inventore repellat omnis esse accusantium, distinctio vel fugit provident quae possimus culpa magni deleniti est, aperiam illo exercitationem dolore, assumenda. Quis.</p>
                    <div class="circle-glyph img-circle"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></div>
                </div>
             <!-- /BOX END-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

And this would be the CSS for most of the above elements:

```
.when{
    @extend .what;
    background:#393F43;
    color:#ddd;
    .title{
        color:#ddd;
    }
    .timeline{
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    color:black;
        &:before{
            content: "";
            width:5px;
            height:100%;
            background:silver;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:50%;
        }
        .entry{
            padding:20px;
            border-radius:2px;
            background:#ecf0f1;
            width:auto;
            max-width:500px;
            color:gray;
            position: relative;
            margin-top:20px;
            p{font-size:14px;}
            &:before{
                content: "";
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                padding:5px;
                left:500px;
                width:35px;
                height:35px;
                background: url(../imgs/arrow.png) no-repeat;
            }
            .circle-glyph{
                background:silver;
                padding:15px;
                width:45px;
                position:absolute;
                left:545px;
                top:10px;
                span{
                    display:block;
                    text-align:center;
                }
            }
            .date-title{
                height:23px;
                div{
                    &:nth-child(1){
                        font-size:15px;
                        font-weight: bold;

                    }
                    &:nth-child(2){
                        text-align:right;
                        font-style:italic;
                        font-size:11px;
                    }
                }
            }
            &:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd){
                margin-top:210px;
            }
            &:nth-child(even){
                float:right;
                .circle-glyph{
                    left:-125px;
                    top:10px;
                }
                &:before{
                content: "";
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                padding:5px;
                left:-35px;
                width:35px;
                height:35px;
                background: url(../imgs/arrow.png) no-repeat;
                -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
                transform: scaleX(-1);
                filter: FlipH;
                -ms-filter: "FlipH";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following: http://piclair.com/data/4xkqg.jpg

Currently in my `script.js` file, I have the following code executing on document load:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.fade').each(function (i) {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

            $(this).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 350);
        }
    });
});
```

^ I did not create the above script.

I've tested it and it works fine on independent elements, for example if I applied it on: `<div class="bg-success fade pad-20">Hello</div>`

It would work individually no matter how many I apply the effect on.

**The Problem**

The problem I'm having is that the fade effect is being triggered for every single `<div class="entry fade">` as soon as *one* is detected by the script in `script.js`

I am guessing it's something to do with how I've nested the different DIVs, classes and elements in general - but I'm not quite sure.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have easy solution, but could you also provide the CSS along, or better provide demo which is either live or [created](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: hmm, I'll try to create a fiddle.

Comment: Basically you have to identify the last object in your vertical timeline, and apply jquery on that one alone! There are different ways to go about it. One way is to apply 'fade' class to the last element you want to fade in, meaning other elements should not have this class. As soon as last element is fadedin, remove class 'fade' right away, as in $element.removeClass("fade"). 
Or another ways is add a class to the last element, and in your jquery code you need to target that instead of .fade.

Comment: But doesn't that mean if I had a timeline with height:2000px, I'd have to scroll all the way to the last one to trigger the visibility for all of them? Or would they still fade in one by one as I'm scrolling down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I'm having is that the fade effect is being triggered for every single`<div class="entry fade">` as soon as one is detected by the script in script.js.

Maybe your saying that they all fade in at the same time. I made a script where they fade in when the bottom of the div hits a certain mark for my example. I don't know if that's what you want. I just changed `position` to `offset`.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
            $(".el").each(function(i){
                console.log($(this).offset().top)
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                $('.display').html("btofWin: " + bottom_of_window + "btmofObj" + bottom_of_object)
                if(bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                    $(this).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    },350)
                }
            })
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8s1cscq5/

I'm learning scroll events myself.

Comment: Wonderful, that is the exact thing I was looking for, and who would have thought all I had to do was change one word?!

Thank you very much sir, really appreciate it :D, and Good luck with learning more about scroll events.